# Como executar uma função a partir de uma url?

Tags: php

Se eu deixar o código logo abaixo avulso dentro do arquivo `funcoes.php` do meu sistema, quando a página recarrega, ele excluir o post que eu mandei excluir.

```
  $tipo   = $_GET['tipo'];
  $funcao = $_GET['funcao']; 

  if($_GET['tipo'] == 'blog' && $_GET['funcao'] == 'excluir'){

    require("classes/Database.php");
    $pdo  = Database::connect();
    $pdo->query("DELETE FROM tb_blog WHERE ID = ".$_GET['id']."");

    echo "
    <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL='>
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
      window.location = \"index\";
    </script>
    "; 

  }
```

Agora se eu colocar esse código dentro de uma `function`, não funciona.

```
  function excluirDados(){
    $tipo   = $_GET['tipo'];
    $funcao = $_GET['funcao']; 

    if($_GET['tipo'] == 'blog' && $_GET['funcao'] == 'excluir'){

      require("classes/Database.php");
      $pdo  = Database::connect();
      $pdo->query("DELETE FROM tb_blog WHERE ID = ".$_GET['id']."");

      echo "
      <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL='>
      <script type=\"text/javascript\">
        window.location = \"index\";
      </script>
      "; 

    }  
  }
```

**Pergunta**: Porque o mesmo código mas dentro de uma função não funciona igual ao código solto dentro do arquivo?

Estou passando essa url: `.../index&tipo=blog&funcao=excluir&id=40`

Comment: primeiro que sua função já esta errada né, deveria ser algo como `function excluirDados() {}` ou somente `function excluir(){}`

Comment: Corrigido !!! :)

Comment: e quando vc passa esses dados para o index ou algum controller, em que momento vc faz a chamada da função excluirDados()?

Comment: Quando eu envio o ***Apagar***, ele faz reload na página e dá include no arquivo **funcoes.php**

Comment: até ai de estar incluindo o arquivo, não significa que vc esta executando a função. Em algum momento vc precisa fazer a chamada da função excluirDados(), antes estava funcionando por estar fora de uma função, agora que vc colocou dentro da função precisa fazer uma chamada da mesma e não somente incluir o arquivo, entendeu?

Comment: Aparece algum erro? undefined index ou algo?

Comment: @rray sem erros ... Marcelo, realmente eu não estava chamando a função.

Answer (score 2):

Pode tentar assim:

```
require("classes/Database.php"); /* requiro fora da função */
function excluirDados(){
    $tipo   = $_GET['tipo'];
    $funcao = $_GET['funcao']; 

    if($_GET['tipo'] == 'blog' && $_GET['funcao'] == 'excluir'){


      $pdo  = Database::connect();
      $pdo->query("DELETE FROM tb_blog WHERE ID = ".$_GET['id']."");

      echo "
      <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL='>
      <script type=\"text/javascript\">
        window.location = \"index\";
      </script>
      "; 

    }  
  }
excluirDados(); /* chamar a função (no seu exemplo ela não estava sendo chamada */
```